# Setting default page for a sub-domain hosted at x10hosting.com

Tags: web-hosting

I have created a sub-domian and I want that as soon as the user goes to that domain, a file named **web.php** should automatically open rather than showind the web directory.
Please tell me if it is possible

Comment: Is your question: How can I force a web.php to be shown by default on sub domains created on a server hosted by x10hosting.com?

Comment: I know you can have apache insert a blank index file in every subdomain for security purposes, but I'm not sure about adding content. May I ask why you need this?

Answer (score 0):

Place an .htaccess file in the root directory of each created sub domain and fill it with:

```
DirectoryIndex web.php
```